# Python Social Auth Error

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using Python Social Auth package for consuming Google OAuth service. It works perfectly fine in my local machine. However, when I deployed the app on a VM linux machine, I get the following error:

```
AuthFailed at /complete/google-oauth2/

Authentication failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)

Exception Type:     AuthFailed
Exception Value:    Authentication failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Can Someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your VM doesn't have access to port 443 (``https``), are you able to do ``wget https://accounts.google.com`` in that VM?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used the same package for testing and was getting the same issue.

If you are using **`http://127.0.0.1:8000`** to hit your server then replace it with **`http://localhost:8000/`** followed by your URL path

Google requires HTTPS requests, so using **localhost** will represent a development server

This has solved the issue for me. I came across this solution from here https://youtu.be/wlcCvzOLL8w